# How to debug the client side code from within studio?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to debug the client side code (like JQuery code, JavaScript code) from within visual studio.

Wondering how i can do that?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it inside of Visual Studio, but I always use Firebug for debugging javascript.

Comment: I m using chrome and its developer tools for this kind of debugging.

Comment: As of now, I am also using Firebug. But i am trying to do it from within Visual studio as i find it convenient. I did this earlier.... I believe it is some settings. and debugger keyword

Comment: I Unchecked the "disable client side scripting" and debugger keyword is not helping... throwing exception at debugger;

Comment: Firebug and Chrome work for debugging but the debugger in Visual Studio really is much better.  Plus if you happen to have an issue that is IE only, debugging in Firebug/Chrome won't help much.  Developers should be familiar with debugging in all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to enable debugging in Internet Explorer.  In Internet Options there's an option, checked by default, called "Disable Script Debugging (Internet Explorer)."  Uncheck this option and close Internet Explorer.

After that, you can use VS to attach to a running instead of IE and set breakpoints in the code.  The full features of VS's debugger will be available and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2010 (and VS 2008 I think) while running the web solution in debug mode using internet explorer, if you go into the Solution Explorer there will be a "Script Documents" node, with an "Internet Explorer" node beneath this and all the java scripts that are in the page will be listed. You can double click on any of these scripts to open them and add breakpoints to the java script as required.

Answer (score 0):

[FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/) is much better javascript debugging tool compared to Visual Studio. I would strongly recommend it to you. [Google Chrome developer tools](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/) are also worth checking.